# Different Types of Packets

Tags: networking, packet-capture

I'm using a sniffer and I would like to know is there a way to tell a download packet from a packet that comes up when you go to a website?  Are the headers different?  If so, what is the difference?  Is the size different?  Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean by *"a download packet"* and *"a packet that comes up when you go to a website"*.

Comment: My sniffer shows me the IP's, sequence and header of a website that I visit.  However I need to differentuate between just visiting a site and downloading from a site, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you mean, but the browser will use the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers to decide whether to display a resource in the browser or to show the Download prompt.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you! Now how van I access this information?  Where does it reside? Will my Sniffer see it?  Any info will be helpful!

Comment: The headers are at the beginning of the HTTP response.  If your sniffer can see the HTTP packets, it can see the response headers.  Have a look with Wireshark, Fiddler, etc.